# Ionic 2: How to overwrite the style of ionic component

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2

I'm new on Ionic 2, I would like to ask how to change the style of ionic component?

I met a problem as shown below:

```
<form action="">
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label fixed>Username</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" value="" clearInput></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
            <ion-label fixed>Password</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="password" clearInput></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</form>
```

The layout will be rendered as:
[image]

There are 3 grey lines between each items, the long one is due to ion-list and the short one is due to ion-item.

I tried to overwrite the style in theme/variables.scss, but it seems there is no setting for it.

I saw deeply in Chrome and found the html is like this
[image]

I don't think overwrite the style of ".list-ios .item-block .item-inner" is a good idea, is there any other way to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to give `no-lines` on this element `<ion-list>`.[**Doc about it**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#list-no-lines).

Like this: [**Working Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/f1ETqg?p=preview)

```
<ion-list no-lines>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label fixed>Username</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label fixed>Password</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="password"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

</ion-list>
```

If you need to learn how to change default them on Ionic2, I highly recommend to read this article.[**A Guide to Styling an Ionic 2 Application**](https://www.joshmorony.com/a-guide-to-styling-an-ionic-2-application/)

You don't need to use `!import` hack if you use styles as shown below inside the page's component. Use `.ios,.md` like this:

*login.scss*

```
 .ios,
    .md {
        page-login {
            .margin-top-35 {
                margin-top: 35px;
            }
         }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

For removing lines there is an attribute for `ion-item`: **`no-lines`**

```
<ion-item no-lines>
            <ion-label fixed>Username</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" value="" clearInput></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
```

There are also [utility attributes](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/theming/css-utilities/) that can be used.

Comment: `!important` is not a way to go in any given situation. It would be best to respect the library that is being used and follow the same pattern and change your Design or use only the provided features.

Comment: @GeorgeAntonakos true.. thats why I had mentioned as a last resort.. removed it anyway..

Answer (score -1):

> Just after your **CSS** property add `!important`.

for eg:

```
    .ion-nav-button-right {
         margin-top: -7px !important;
         margin-right: 0 !important;
    }
```

For your problem , just remove the label  like:

```
<ion-item style="background: #f3f3f3 !important">
          <ion-input  type="text" placeholder="Write Your Comments"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
```

Comment: `!important` is not an acceptable answer if we want to keep a project maintainable and reusable. Also inlining styles also is something that destroys the specificity in the css and renders the project not maintainable. That's the reason I down voted.

Comment: @GeorgeAntonakos accepted your suggestions , that's the reason i upvoted

Comment: @George Antonakos  I feel in Ionic when most of element styling happens during the run time. You will not be aware which class that are getting added to element. since you cannot see those classes directly in the code. So you may need to add !important some times.

Comment: @Vasanth I agree with you. Also, when you have a custom component and you want an specific style, it is a very dirty solution to write the same structure for each platform (md, ios, etc) to change one or more properties. !important, on this case, is a good solution and not always is so bad.